# Python3 - Shorten path for home directory in Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu

What I have is a path of a file which is in the home directory, and I wish to process it to become shorten path which includes "~" in it.

For example, my input could be:

`"/home/username/test"` or `/home/./username/test` or `/home/../home/username/test`

and I wish to get

`~/test`

I tried to `.split("/")` and match the first 2 terms, but when it's a little more complicated with all those "." and ".." I have no idea how to achieve this.

How do I process paths in an efficient way to achieve the above goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [os.path.realpath](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.realpath) to convert a path to canonical form and then check if the beginning is the same as a home directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
from pathlib import Path
home_path = str(Path.home())
```

Here is the documentation [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.home)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help!

My final solution using `os.path.realpath()` is as follow

Please comment if I have done something wrong or if there is a better way!

```py
from os import path

def getShortPath(p):
    realpath = path.realpath(p).split("/")[1:]
    homepath = path.expanduser("~").split("/")[1:]
    if realpath[:2] == homepath:
        processed = "~"
        realpath = realpath[2:]
    else: processed = "/"
    for i in realpath:
        processed = path.join(processed,i)
    return processed
```